# Как автоматизировать работу скрипта PHP

Tags: php

Пишу простой скрипт который отправляет содержимое писем с электронной почты в тг на PHP.
У меня такой вопрос, каким образом реализовать автоматическую работу скрипта без участия клиента ?
Пример: Приходит письмо на почту и оно сразу же уходит в тг

Comment: чтобы сразу же, это почтовый сервер каким то образом дергать ваш скрипт должен. А если не совсем сразу же, то это вам надо ходить опрашивать почтовый сервер на предмет писем, и отсылать уведомление. при этом запоминать, чего последнее уже было известно и отправлено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Как автоматизировать работу скрипта PHP ?

---

Благодаря пользователю [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran), я стал изучать данную тему по выполнению автоматической работы скриптов.
В итоге я пришел к выводу что нужно использовать **cron**.
Составив расписание выполнения скрипта, мне удалось заставить скрипт проверять почту на наличие новых писем через определенный интервал и отправлять их в ТГ.

Comment: Если у кого-то есть более изящные решения данного вопроса, отпишитесь в комментариях.